# memory game getting pictures that are displayed in grids to show correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I am following the guide here:
https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-create-a-memory-game-super-mario-with-plain-javascript/
I was on the first step where you add the images and get them into a grid.
Please see code below. However when you load the index.html page on a web browser it's blank.
I'm not seeing any console errors and when you inspect the element for the grid you see:

```
    <div class="card" data-name="star" style="background-image: 
    url("img/star.png");"></div>
```

which is supposed to be correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
      const cardsArray = [{
      'name': 'shell',
     'img': 'img/blueshell.png',
      },
      {
       'name': 'star',
      'img': 'img/star.png',
      },
      {
     'name': 'bobomb',
     'img': 'img/bobomb.png',
      },
      {
     'name': 'mario',
     'img': 'img/mario.png',
      },
      {
      'name': 'luigi',
      'img': 'img/luigi.png',
       },
       {
      'name': 'peach',
      'img': 'img/peach.png',
       },
       {
      'name': '1up',
      'img': 'img/1up.png',
      },
      {
       'name': 'mushroom',
       'img': 'img/mushroom.png',
        },
        {
       'name': 'thwomp',
      'img': 'img/thwomp.png',
       }];
       const game = document.getElementById('game');
      const grid = document.createElement('section');
      grid.setAttribute('class', 'grid');
      game.appendChild(grid);

      cardsArray.forEach(item => {
      const card = document.createElement('div');
      card.classList.add('card');
      card.dataset.name = item.name;
      card.style.backgroundImage = `url(${item.img})`;
      grid.appendChild(card);
       });


        body {
           margin: 20px 0;
           background: #6589F9;
            }

         .grid {
            max-width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-evenly;

            }

          .card {
            margin: 5px;
            background-color: #6589F9;
            background-size: contain;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            height: 150px;
            width: 150px; 


            }
```

Comment: Hi no, they are in the img folder. When you launch index.html in a browser.
You can get to the img folder and see the images correctly.

Comment: have you defined the width and height of the card class?

Comment: @Rahul yes the root folder is memory folder -> index.html is inside there.
img folder is inside memory folder

Comment: @bowl_of_rice if you don't define the div width and height it will have 0 width/height based on the content that in this case is none. The div doesn't know the size of the background image or something like that, you need to set it.

Comment: @bowl_of_rice, Ok, then where have you defined the `grid` class?

Comment: style.css

                 .grid {
             max-width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
          display: flex;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-between;

              }

             .card {
               margin: 5px;
        background-color: #6589F9;
               background-size: contain;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: center center;
       height: 150px;
       width: 150px;
               }

Comment: I have the height and width set in css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all your css you have added in comment, its working fine for me. I have just changed the image path from img to source (https://taniarascia.github.io/memory/img). So I am guessing its the problem with your image path.

```js
const cardsArray = [{
      'name': 'shell',
     'img': 'img/blueshell.png',
      },
      {
       'name': 'star',
      'img': 'img/star.png',
      },
      {
     'name': 'bobomb',
     'img': 'img/bobomb.png',
      },
      {
     'name': 'mario',
     'img': 'img/mario.png',
      },
      {
      'name': 'luigi',
      'img': 'img/luigi.png',
       },
       {
      'name': 'peach',
      'img': 'img/peach.png',
       },
       {
      'name': '1up',
      'img': 'img/1up.png',
      },
      {
       'name': 'mushroom',
       'img': 'img/mushroom.png',
        },
        {
       'name': 'thwomp',
      'img': 'img/thwomp.png',
       }];
       
       /* I am using image from the srouce */
       var base = 'https://taniarascia.github.io/memory/';
       
       
       const game = document.getElementById('game');
      const grid = document.createElement('section');
      grid.setAttribute('class', 'grid');
      game.appendChild(grid);

      cardsArray.forEach(item => {
      const card = document.createElement('div');
      card.classList.add('card');
      card.dataset.name = item.name;
      card.style.backgroundImage = `url(${base + item.img})`;
      grid.appendChild(card);
       });
```

```css
.grid { max-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-between; }

.card { margin: 5px; background-color: #6589F9; background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; height: 150px; width: 150px; }
```

```html
<div class="card" data-name="star" style="background-image: 
    url('https://taniarascia.github.io/memory/img/star.png');"></div>
<div id="game">

</div>
```

You can also test it here..
https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/ovqj9wsa/3/

Comment: This part is supposed to create the div's and the grid's I'm not supposed to have to create it manually.

                  cardsArray.forEach(item => {
                const card = document.createElement('div');
                card.classList.add('card');
  card.dataset.name = item.name;
  card.style.backgroundImage = `url(${item.img})`;
  grid.appendChild(card);
});

Comment: I can load the index.html in a web browser and inspect the element and get the images to display in the browser from that page though

Comment: Then you must be having some CSS problem. Can you please add your all CSS?

Comment: By the way I am not adding any divs manually. I have just added div with `game` id as you wrote `const game = document.getElementById('game');` in the javascript

Comment: Its working fine for me! I have created html page and downloaded all the images to my img folder beside html file. Its working fine!

Comment: Make sure you have added `<div id="game"></div>` in your html.

Comment: You were right my css link was wrong:
<link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
changed to
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

and now the images are showing up.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be there in your `style` property. You had used `""` (double quotes) around image source, instead you should use `''`.

```
<div class="card" data-name="star" style="background-image: url('img/star.png');"></div>
```